# ui:inputCheckbox not getting slds-styled when used as ltng:out in VF page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds, style

I have a lightning component inside VF page and I am using ui:inputCheckbox there many times.

> Example:

```
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="isShown" label="Show"
                          class="slds-checkbox"
                          labelClass="slds-form-element__label"/>
```

> However, I am not able to get it styled like slds as below:

[image]

> Instead it is shown like the old one:

[image]

The styling applies to other elements but not only to checkbox. Also, there is no thing as lightning:checkbox. How to get it styled slds way? When added the component to lightning app builder, this style applies but not when added in a VF page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is what did I did to get the slds style on checkboxes.

```
<label class="slds-checkbox">
    <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.isShown}" />
    <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
    <span class="slds-form-element__label">Show</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `lightning:input` of type checkbox where it automatically applies SLDS and hence is easier to use. It has disadvantage of event.getSource() function not working though, but only till Winter17 as from Spring 17 , it will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

lightning:input is still in beta: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm, thus cannot use it.